# Objects.keys inside return stateless component , Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

I have this return in a statless component, i'm using Object.keys to try print test divs:

```
  return (
   <div>Object.keys(subfields).map( function (item )  {
      return (
        <div>test/div>
      );
     });
   </div>);
```

but i'm gettint 'unexpected token' in the line with 'return'
what is happening, i know you can avoid return , but i'd like to use it to test things and print on the console, and i think the code is clear to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `Object.keys` in `{}` in order to make it work. 
I also see a missing `<` right after `test` in your code :)

```
return (
  <div>
    {Object.keys(subfields).map(item =>
      <div>test</div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

Or:

```
return (
  <div>
    {Object.keys(subfields).map(function(item) {
      return <div>test</div>
    })}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must "escape" back from jsx to javascript before the Object.keys call, as well if you want to use the map value in the returned jsx

```
return (
    <div>
        { Object.keys(subfields).map(item => <div>{item}</div>) }
    </div>
);
```